# How can I grab the 'e' value that is automatically passed as the first parameter of an event handler?

Tags: events, parameters, bind, addeventlistener, eventhandler

Just curious, is there a way to grab the 'e' value that is automatically passed as the first parameter of an event handler in the following code, so that I can use bind

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(a + b); //3
  console.log(e); //where does e come from and how do i bind it below?
}.bind(null, [e value], 1, 2));
```

Is this possible in the case that I wanted to bind the event handler to predefined parameters to use inside the function?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here? The last bit is confusing

Comment: I want to be able to bind parameter values to the event handler.  But, I'm not sure how to grab the 'e' value so I can bind the parameter values it without overwriting it.  I'm just curious if it's possible.